# paperclip image size notations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, amazon-s3, paperclip

At the beginning it seemed to me a like a mistype but now as I see more examples I realize its not..

I see `:thumb => "300x300>"`

or `:thumb => "100x100#"`

and even `:thumb => "180"`

what do these mean? Where can I find explanation for that notation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the [git repository](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation) where it is developed. Explanation copied from there:

**Resizing options**

Default behavior is to resize the image and maintain aspect ratio (i.e. the :medium version of a 300×150 image will be 200×100). Some commonly used options are:

- trailing #, thumbnail will be centrally cropped, ensuring the requested dimensions.
- trailing >, thumbnail will only be modified if it is currently larger requested dimensions. (i.e. the :small thumb for a 120×80 original image will be unchanged)

Comment: horray! I was looking for that!